# Can't add user: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UsersController)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I'm at chapter 7.2 Signup form in Hartls tutorial but I have run into some issues. I don't get the ForbiddenAttributes (Fig 7.15) as in the tutorial.

I can access my /signup but whenever I submit a user with wrong attributes (mail/password) it throws a 500, "We're sorry, but something went wrong.". Not the above mentioned ForbiddenAttributes.

A snippet from the server log:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-08-01 22:19:59 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UsersController):
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
```

I have narrowed it down to the resources: users in my routes.rb. But can't pinpoint it. Reason I narrowed it down is whenever I interchange 'users' with 'user' the /signup stop working and I get this instead

```
if options.empty?
  recipient.send(method, *args)
else
  recipient.send(method, *args, options)
end
```

While /signup stops working my users/1 (show) starts working which it does not do with 'users' in route.

Code:

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :user

  root              'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' =>     'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' =>    'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' =>  'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' =>   'user#new'
  get 'users/:id' => 'user#show'

end
```

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:users])
    if @user.save
      #Successfull
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                            uniqueness: { case_sensetive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with `UserController`, as your code expects `UsersController` for action.

Controller names are always in plural as per convention. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#controller-naming-convention

try changing the `UserController` to `UsersController`

secondly change the `resources :user` to `resources :users` 
Also inside your app/view folder there is a folder named `user`. you need to rename that folder to `users`

Rather generate controller for users. and delete the one for user but that might lose your data. you need to make sure of copy stuff from user to users files.

Things will work.

Comment: To clarify Athars answer, he means changing the name of the view folder 'user' to 'users' - plural. Also, the filename of user_controller.rb needs to be changed to users_controller.rb togheter with the class name.

Comment: Thank Mikael. i will also update my answer to be much better. and you can feel free to to accept that.:D